# cmake+Eclipse/Nsight: Compiler (nvcc) error parsing?

Tags: eclipse, cuda, cmake, eclipse-cdt, nsight

I am using CMake to generate project files for Nsight (=beefed up version of Eclipse CDT) for a CUDA project.
The problem is, that **Eclipse does parse the compiler errors generated by nvcc**.

I enabled the "nvcc error parser" in "project->properties->C/C++ Make 
Project->Error Parsers" and moved it to the top of the list, to no effect.
Error parsing works fine for "native" nsight CUDA projects and for 
non-CUDA/non-nvcc c++ cmake generated projects.

The CMakeLists.txt is very basic:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project(myproject)

find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
set(CUDA_SOURCES 
    myprojmain.cu
    )

cuda_add_executable( myproject ${CUDA_SOURCES})
```

Comment: I opened a bug for this issue:
http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=15277

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I traced down the root cause of this.
In the .project XML project file, the sub-tree

projectDescription/buildSpec/buildCommand/arguments/dictionary/*

contains key/value pairs.

```
<key>org.eclipse.cdt.core.errorOutputParser</key>
```

configures the list of error parsers:

```
<value>nvcc.errorParser;org.eclipse.cdt.core.VCErrorParser;org.eclipse.cdt.core.GmakeErrorParser;org.eclipse.cdt.core.MakeErrorParser;org.eclipse.cdt.core.GCCErrorParser;org.eclipse.cdt.core.GASErrorParser;org.eclipse.cdt.core.WorkingDirLocator;org.eclipse.cdt.core.GLDErrorParser;</value>
```

For nvcc error parsing to work, nvcc.errorParse must be in the list. Order matters, so it is probably best to put it in front.

I hacked together a little python script for my personal use which patches Eclipse CDT projects accordingly. It is attached as fix-cmake-nsight-err-0.01.tar.gz to the cmake bug
http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=15277
Would be nice to see this integrated into CMake some time...